# Antd input value changes on scroll

Tags: reactjs, antd

When the input box is on focus mode and the user scrolls up the value if the number auto increases and when scrolls down the value decrease automatically. this effect is only noticed on some input components, not all even though the code is literally the same just placeholder value changes can anyone knows the reason for this? I know I can stop this by preventDefault on scroll events but I want to know the reason behind it. thanks

this is code where the number increases or decreases based on scroll

```
    <Input
      onChange={(e) =>
        updateAssembledInputs({
          key: 'assembledArray',
          value: {
            id: ele.id,
            key: 'quantity',
            value: e.target.value,
          },
        })
      }
      value={ele.productItems[0]?.quantity}
      type="number"
      onKeyDown={(evt) => INPUT_TYPE_NUMBER.includes(evt.key) && evt.preventDefault()}
      bordered={false}
      className="h-10 text-normal font-semibold font-montserrat
                   text-baby-elephant"
      suffix="UNITS"
    />
```

this is code where nothing happens

```
    <Input
      onChange={(e) =>
        updateAssembledInputs({
          key: 'assembledArray',
          value: {
            id: ele.id,
            key: 'minimalStockLimit',
            value: e.target.value,
          },
        })
      }
      value={ele.minimalStockLimit}
      type="number"
      onKeyDown={(evt) => INPUT_TYPE_NUMBER.includes(evt.key) && evt.preventDefault()}
      bordered={false}
      className="h-10 text-normal font-semibold font-montserrat text-baby-elephant"
      suffix="UNITS"
    />
```

Comment: can you provide your code on a sandbox ?

Answer (score 1):

This bug happens because of the type="number". If you are using Input form Ant Design, you can add a regex inside the rules (in pattern) to avoid everything that is not a number, then you can use type="text"

Answer (score 0):

you can add attribute onWheel and handle the event like this to prevent changing value when scrolling at input number antd:

```
onWheel={(e) => e.currentTarget.blur()}
```

I have try it in antd version 5.11.1 and it's work for me